# How can I use variables from bash in url curl command on Jenkins instance?

Tags: python, bash, variables, jenkins

I trigger python script in bash shell.The results of python script is number. I need this number as variable in bash and I want to use it to url in curl command.

Here are exemplary data but I want to explain what I mean:

```
POST=$(python3 /repo/post.py)
echo "${POST}"
echo "curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ExampleToken" "https://wikipedia.org/api/post/${POST/?format=json""
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ExampleToken" "https://wikipedia.org/api/post/${POST}/?format=json"
```

output:

```
30
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ExampleToken" "https://wikipedia.org/api/post/30/?format=json"
<h1>Server error</h1>
<p>An unspecified error occured.</p>
```

But when I write manually this number I mean:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ExampleToken" "https://wikipedia.org/api/post/30/?format=json"
```

I get right output.

I wonder because I run this curl command on Jenkins where whole script is writing in the bash. But this python script which I trigger, it uses json file which obtained from earlier command curl . And if I trigger Jenkins job using my repo (where json file is saved on my repo) this curl command:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ExampleToken" "https://wikipedia.org/api/post/${POST}/?format=json"
```

is working but if I save this json file on Jenkins workspace then this curl command is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation:

- The script retrieves the value of the environment parameter and stores it in a variable.
- It defines the api_key variable with your actual API key.
- The URL is constructed using string interpolation. Special characters in the environment value are replaced with their URL-encoded equivalents using replaceAll.
- The curl command is executed with appropriate options:
  **-X POST**: Specifies a POST request method.
  **-u ${api_key}**:: Provides basic authentication using the API key.
  **$url**: Inserts the constructed URL.
  **-d '{"data": "some value"}'**: Sends JSON data in the request body.

```html
pipeline {
  agent any

  parameters {
    string(name: 'environment', defaultValue: 'staging')
  }

  stages {
    stage('API Call') {
      steps {
        script {
          def environment = params.environment
          def api_key = 'your_api_key' // Replace with your actual API key

          // URL with string interpolation and escaping
          def url = "https://api.example.com/v1/resource/${environment.replaceAll(/\s/, '%20')}"

          sh "curl -X POST -u ${api_key}: $url -d '{\"data\": \"some value\"}'"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, but unfortunately this Jenkins job is not a pipeline...